# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK2CustomerId' on table 'tblMaintenance' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql-server

I create a table that has the relationship with 2 another tables. But when I try to connect FK from another table it shows this warning:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK1VehicleID' on table 'tblMaintenance' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints

Here is what I wrote:

```
CREATE TABLE tblMaintenance
(  
    MaintenanceID Int Identity(1,1) Primary Key,
    Description VarChar(100),
    Date Date,
    TotalAmount Money, 
    VehicleID Int,
    CustomerID Int, 
    PurchaseID Int,

    Constraint FK2CustomerID 
        Foreign Key(CustomerID) References tblCustomer(CustomerID)
            ON DELETE Cascade On Update Cascade,
    Constraint FK1VehicleID 
        Foreign Key(VehicleID) References tblVehicle(VehicleID)
            ON DELETE Cascade On Update Cascade,
)
Go
```

Here is another statements that related to statement above:

```
 --**Table tblCustomer
 Create Table tblCustomer
(
  CustomerID Int Identity(1,1) Primary Key,
  CustomerName VarChar(30),
  Address VarChar(150),
  Phone VarChar(30)
)
Go
---------------End Table tblCustomer------------------------------------
--**Table tblVehicle
Create Table tblVehicle
(
  VehicleID Int Identity(1,1) Primary Key,
  Brand VarChar(30), 
  PlateNumber VarChar(30), 
  EngineNumber VarChar(30),
  CustomerID Int, 
  CustomerName VarChar(30),

  Constraint FK1CustomerID 
      ForeignKey(CustomerID) References tblCustomer(CustomerID)
            On Delete Cascade On Update Cascade
)
Go
---------------End Table tblVehicle------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please show us the T-SQL statement you've used that actually caused this warning

Comment: Thank for your help. Here is mine:
--**Table tblCustomer
Create Table tblCustomer(
CustomerID Int Identity(1,1) Primary Key,
CustomerName VarChar(30),
 Address VarChar(150),
 Phone VarChar(30))
Go
---------------End Table tblCustomer------------------------------------

Comment: --**Table tblVehicle<br />
Create Table tblVehicle(
VehicleID Int Identity(1,1) Primary Key,
Brand VarChar(30), 
PlateNumber VarChar(30),
EngineNumber VarChar(30),
CustomerID Int, 
CustomerName VarChar(30),
Constraint FK1CustomerID Foreign Key(CustomerID) References tblCustomer(CustomerID)
On Delete Cascade On Update Cascade
)
Go
---------------End Table tblVehicle------------------------------------

Comment: Sorry I can't break line in comment. I am a new user in stackoverflow.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: I've edited already. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day,

> in SQL Server, a table cannot appear more than one time in a list of all the cascading referential actions that are started by either a DELETE or an UPDATE statement.

For full explanation, a simple workaround, and more info go to the official document here (which is the source of the quote above):
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/321843/error-message-1785-occurs-when-you-create-a-foreign-key-constraint-tha

----- UPDATE Israel Time 2018-08-12 22:40 ------

I will try to explain the reason Microsoft Team chose to prevent Structure like this...

Lets assume that we have the following three tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A;
create table A (Aid NVARCHAR(3) primary key)
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B;
Create Table B(
    Bid NVARCHAR(3) primary key,
    Aid NVARCHAR(3)
)
Go

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS C;
Create Table C(
    Cid NVARCHAR(3) primary key,
    Aid NVARCHAR(3),
    Bid NVARCHAR(3)
)
Go

Insert A(Aid) values ('a1'),('a2'),('a3'),('a4')
Insert B(Bid, Aid) values ('b1','a1'),('b2','a1'),('b3','a2')
Insert C(Cid,Bid, Aid) values ('c1','b1','a2'),('c2','b1','a2'),('c3','b2','a2'),('c4','b3','a4')
GO

SELECT * FROM A
SELECT * FROM B
SELECT * FROM C
GO
```

Think about a case that these tables were in hard relations (Using FOREIGN KEY) according to the columns name and these FK were "On Delete Cascade On Update Cascade".

1. Now let's delete from table A the row a1
2. Since we configured FK Cascade from Table B, then the relevant rows in Table B should be deleted: Meaning that rows b1, b2 should be deleted
3. But since table C has FK to B then we need to delete the relevant rows to b1,b2 in table C. Meaning we delete rows c1,c2, and c3
4. and now we have the issue! Since table C also related to table A and we deleted row c3 which is related to rows a2 (which we did not deleted)! Now the question raise what to do regarding row a2 in table A. We deleted his children so let's delete it...
5. One second... The issue continue... now we deleted row a2 in table A. therefore we need to delete row b3 in table B, therefore we need to delete row c4 in table C...

Theoretically there is no restriction to do so, and continue the task until we are done... There are database servers that allow this structure.

With that being said this case lead to very poor performance and confusion regarding what is deleted when we simply wanted to delete a single row and we get into loop of deletion. SQL Server does not allow this structure by design if we also want to use Cascade! In order to prevent cases like this, the SQL Server team choose to prevent structure like this together with automatic deletion (On Delete Cascade). In fact if you design the database in the right way, we should not get to this requirement probably.

> **Note!** this case is what called "multiple cascade paths", which is not extreme as the case of Infinite cycles.
>
> **Note!** I examine here with DELETE but the same issue and the same rules are relevant to UPDATE as well. If you must have this structure then you can drop the Cascade and control the deletions from the children yourself.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I put a foreign key CustomerID on Table Vehicle and On Table Maintenance. After that, I put a foreign key of VehicleID on Table Maintenance.I think the problem is CustomerID have more than one path of Delete Cascade Update Cascade to same Table Maintenance.

Comment: This is exactly the issue as explained in the link I gave you. Thinks about this (Tables A,B,C). B point to A and C point to A and to B as well. If you configure ON DELETE Cascade then if row X in A is deleted then the relevant rows (the children) in B should be deleted as well, and the relevant rows in C (since both tables points to A with Cascade). Until here all well, but now since you deleted the rows in B you should deleted the relevant rows in C since C point to B as well. But we already deleted rows from C since the deletion from A...this structure is not allowed in SQL Server by design

Comment: By the way, there are other server which allow this structure. This structure is potential for issues and each designer can choose how he deal these unique cases - as mentioned in SQL Server Microsoft team choose not to allow this structure.

Comment: Your design make no sense. How Maintenance can be related to both specific Customer and to specific Vehicle, and on the same time the Vehicle related to Customer. Don't you see the cycles that can be here? Usually Maintenance related to the Vehicle. And Customer related to the Vehicle. but you do not related Customer to the Maintenance! the relation come from the Vehicle. If you need multiple to multiple relation that you simply use another relation table but again the relation are (Maintenance-Vehicle) and (Vehicle-Customer)

Comment: I hat this interface!!!! I cannot continue split a simple explanation to multiple comment :-(

Comment: check my update to the answer. I think it explain all :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer explain all I want.

Comment: You are most welcome @LimKimChheng `;-)`. You can vote as useful if you think that this can help others as well.

Comment: Sorry I have only 8 reputation. I really want to vote your answer too, but Stackoverflow require 15 reputation to vote up for useful answer. I could only check tick on your answer. Could you vote my question, Please? I think I might get more reputation when someone vote my question.

Comment: I am really sorry for that. I will come back when I have enough reputation.

Comment: That is OK `:-)` . I am not using stackoverflow a lot (prefer MSDN forums) and I was not aware that this feature related to reputation. There is no need to comeback for this, but you are welcome to come back to help others or if you have more questions. Have a great day (here some more points for you... I learned about this limitation now)